# how can i create a dialog in flutter with accessing the screen while it is called

Tags: flutter, dart

``import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../static/my_icon_icons.dart';

Checkout(BuildContext context){

return showDialog(

```
context: context,

builder: (BuildContext context) {

  int ? CurrentPaymentMethod = 1;

  return Padding(

    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(250,662,250,0),

    child: Dialog(
```

Answer (score 0):

For your dialog to show will you are still in your current screen put in a Button, GestureDetector or InkWell

```
onPressed: () {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Dialog Title'),
            content: Text('This is my content'),
        )
    );
}
```